# Service in android is not restarting

Tags: android, service

I am using services in android for some tasks, I want my service to run every time.
But when I clear ram of android phone my service get killed and not restarting.
I have read several articles which suggest `START_STICKY` will solve the problem but it is not happening.

Below is my code of `onStartCommand` in service, i am returning `START_STICKY` in it. Even `onDestroy` is not getting called in this situation.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int start_Id) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: it is restarted if the OS shuts down your service, if you do that it is NOT

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: I am using API level 24

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function to restart service once it stopped forcefully.

Note: If you are also stopping this service from somewhere else then also it will restart the service again so for that you have to keep a check in this function that either you stop service or it's stopped forcefully. 
If you are stopping service yourself then save state of service stop type[Not Forcefully] in shared preferences and use that state check to not start it again.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

Comment: This code did not works for me, but i noticed one thing that when i cleared RAM of my mobile onTaskRemoved() method get called. In onTaskRemoved method i am sending a broadcast. In broadcast reveiver i am restarting my service. after broadcast receiver get called my service onStartCommand() method get called, But now my service is not visible in running process of my mobile device.